# Question regarding paid agencies that help students apply to grad school abroad

Tags: discussion, support

In a recent [question about applying to grad school](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/58002/publishing-code-in-order-to-improve-my-chances-to-be-admitted-in-university?noredirect=1#comment136178_58002), I discovered that the OP was paying an agency to assist with the application process.  I suppose, in a way, this is a bit like paying someone to do prepare your tax return for you.

If someone mentions hiring such an agency here at Academia, is it okay to say to the OP, "If you want to skip the middleman and prepare your own application, you are welcome to ask specific questions about the process here as you go along?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not even sure why you would ask that; you can definitely do that. The main point of this forum is to provide answers to questions, but frequently people don't realize what their question should be, and comments are often used to help guide the OP towards asking a better question. I say go for it!

Comment: I asked to make sure.  It would not be nice to offer the help and then find out that's not kosher.